# Miniconda virtualenvs activation 'source activate' vs. 'conda activate'

Tags: python, eclipse, pip, virtualenv, miniconda

Installed miniconda
created my first virtualenv called ai37 (python 3.7)
created my 2nd virtualenv called da35 (python 3.5)

Will it be an issue that I created a new env called `da35` without first deactivating my first created env called `ai37`...meaning did I create a virtualenv nested in a virtualenv? when i tried to use

`$ source activate da35` the output said

> source: no such file or directory: activate

so I then deactivated it and tried it again however when using

`$ conda activate` like it says to, I think I activated a directory within a directory and had to enter deactivate twice to get back to my base. **Any help understanding this?**

I was learning from this video and the guy did it but his 2nd source activate cmd didn't output the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23aQdrS58e0

I previously installed homebrew so already had python 3.8. I also installed eclipse and virtualenv and pip already came with the homebrew packages. Basically I learned of miniconda as I had just finished setting up my first virtual env with the 'pip/virtualenv' way only to find conda has greater flexibility.

For context,  when I entered

```
$ conda env list
```

I also got the

> "/Users/meusr/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216:
> UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore
> objects to clean up at shutdown   warnings.warn('resource_tracker:
> There appear to be %d '"